# Pass argument store in variable to argparse

Tags: python

This is my script mytest.py.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Params")
parser.add_argument(
        "--value")

def test(args):
  print(args.value)

args = parser.parse_args()
test(args)
```

I want to pass argument store in variable `val`

```
val =1
!python mytest.py --value val
```

instead of printing 1 it print `val`. How to send 1 stored in variable val.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` always get argument as string, or list of strings on default, and what you do on your shell is irrelevant with python program. It is no wonder `val` is printed.

Use file that contains "1" and read that file to do what you intended to.

Comment: is there any solution or alternate way?

Comment: I'm afraid to tell you that neither `export` nor `alias` in shell does not work. I guess the best way is to use file and read the content.

Answer (score 0):

As jueon park said naming a variable in commandline wont work
[image]

It would create an error like the above one.If you are calling the command from any programer will work but in cmd it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late for this but your python code works just fine. The problem you have is that you are not passing the arguments correctly.

For this to work first you need to correctly set the variable:

```
val=1
```

(note that the "=" must be next to both the variable name and the value)

and the you can simply use $ to get the value from the variable. So:

```
python mytest.py --value $val
```